# How to read a json_decode result and dump it?

Tags: php, json, jsonresponse

i have a little problem with my json response.

I dumped it in my php code, and the result is what i attached here

How can I dump the `statusText` ?

I've already tried to decode it, and i've tried this too:

```
dump($myVar['statusText']);
```

or something like that

(to obtain the dump of my json i've posted, i've just did
`dump($myVar);`  )

```
JsonResponse {#325
  #data: "{"code":"OK","status":"ok","data":{"UUID":"f239ae18-98af-4224-8b4f-7713c71a5576","order":{something here },"orderRows":[something else here}}"
  #callback: null
  #encodingOptions: 271
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#326
    #computedCacheControl: array:2 [
      "no-cache" => true
      "private" => true
    ]
    #cookies: []
    #headerNames: array:4 [
      "content-type" => "Content-Type"
      "access-control-allow-origin" => "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
      "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
      "date" => "Date"
    ]
    #headers: array:4 [
      "content-type" => array:1 [
        0 => "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      ]
      "access-control-allow-origin" => array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      "cache-control" => array:1 [
        0 => "no-cache, private"
      ]
      "date" => array:1 [
        0 => "Mon, 06 May 2019 08:15:28 GMT"
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  #content: "{"code":"OK","status":"ok","data":{"UUID":"f239ae18-98af-4224-8b4f-7713c71a5576","order":{something},"orderRows":[something else}}"
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
}
```

Just wanna see
`"status" => 'ok'` and my life would be perfect  :D

Comment: is this from laravel? there's a class and documentation for that already https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html, there's a [`->status`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html#method_status) exposed already that you can use. and other methods [`->getData()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html#method_getData) as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this output, it looks like the code is stored in the content also.

> "status":"ok"

For this reason, following [this documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html#method_getData) on the `getData()` method, you should be able to retrieve the status:

```
$data = $myVar->getData();
var_dump($data->status);
```

It is expected that this would return a string of "ok".

Comment: i've tried in that way, but needless to say, it didn't work out. At the end, I have read with more attention the php documentation of json_encode and json_decode and i found out that if i pass as 2 par. "true", my object become an array. That's all ! Ty for the answer btw!!